# Get JSON Response on HTTP GET in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I create controller and html page And I want get http response with JSON string But I do not see nothing.

```
angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
            templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
            controller: 'View3Ctrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('View3Ctrl',function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.my_name = "Pasha";
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=#APIKEY&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        });
    });
```

It is my html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My view</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="View3Ctrl">
<p> Hello Pavel</p>
<div>{{my_name}}</div>
<div>{{myWelcome}}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And after load page I get this result

> Hello Pavel
>
> Pasha
>
> Angular seed app: v0.1

But I want see JSON result too

Comment: Use ng-repeat if you want to see all data

Comment: though the whole, at least in the form of the object, at least one field, at least something that will show me that the query returned data

Comment: Wasn't this question already asked?

Comment: try with response instead of response.data

Comment: I have tried on every

Comment: Create a plunker if you want a quick answer

Comment: What means "plunker "??????

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/AKbzuWmkuJ7T2SG9aUZB

Comment: It seems that the API endpoint is not in JSON format.

Answer (score -1):

Modify your html like this.
Here you are iteration over the whole data array and printing one bye one.

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My view</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp.view3" ng-controller="View3Ctrl">
<p> Hello Pavel</p>

<div ng-repeat="row in myWelcome">
    <div>{{row.my_name}}</div>
    <div>{{row.myWelcome}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

copy the url service that u want to call on the browser then, see the JSON results. U will be see that the returned JSON didn't have a data object or status text object. That's mean u can print the JSON with this code:

```
angular.module('myApp.view3', ['ngRoute'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/view3', {
            templateUrl: 'view3/view3.html',
            controller: 'View3Ctrl'
        });
    }])

    .controller('View3Ctrl',function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.my_name = "Pasha";
        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "http://api.geosvc.com/rest/US/84606/nearby?apikey=4ff687893a7b468cb520b3c4e967c4da&d=20&pt=PostalCode&format=json"
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('angularTable', []);

app.controller('listdata',function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.users = []; //declare an empty array
    $http.get("mockJson/mock.json").success(function(response)
    { 
        $scope.users = response;  //ajax request to fetch data into   
    });

});
```

**index.html**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.hobby}}</td>
</tr>
```